# How to stop _wpnonce and _wp_http_referer from appearing in URL

Tags: search, nonce, wp-list-table

I am trying to develop a plug-in that has a search field and uses WP_List_Table.
The plug-in is strictly for the backend and searches the users in the database and returns them along with some other meta from an additional plug-in.

When I do a search for the user the hidden input fields of _wpnonce and _wp_http_referer are added to the url string. The _wpnonce is not that big of a deal but the _wp_http_referer is a problem.

If the person using the plug-in keeps doing multiple searches the _wp_http_referer string becomes so long in the URL that it gives an error:
    Request-URI Too Large
    The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

So how do I either stop the hidden values from appearing in the URL or reset _wp_http_referer each time the search button is clicked?

Comment: Which table class you are extending? This doesn't seem like something root `WP_List_Table` does.

Comment: I am extending the WP_List_Table. I am using the search_box() to search the users in the database. I have this and the display() wrapped in a form with method="get" and action="". Everything works it displays table fine, returns data fine. But I during testing every time I search the _wp_http_referer gets added to the previous one. And appears in the URL.

Comment: How much control do you have over the code that's generating the form? Can't you use POST instead of GET? Can't you filter out the '_wp_http_referer' parameter from the previous URL?

Comment: I tried to follow what the core was using and that was GET. POST kept the url clean but when I tried it would return nothing in the list.

Comment: take a look at wp-admin/edit.php it checks for any actions and removes the query arguments then redirects. I've added a filter on the init action to do something similar.

Answer (score 4):

This issue arrises because of a couple of problems:

1) `WP_List_Table::search_box()` inserts the default `_wpnonce` and `_wp_http_referer` fields by using `wp_nonce_field()` without giving you the ability to override and say "I've already go a nonce field thanks".

2) You need to use `GET` as your method of form submission when subclassing `WP_List_Table` because `WP_List_Table::print_column_headers()` only checks `$_GET` for the current `orderby` and `order` parameters and uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for constructing its header links. If you don't use `GET` as the form method you'll loose the search parameter when sorting a column.

There are a couple of ways to stop the `Request-URI Too Large The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server` error:

A) Because all the nonce checking functions are able to use either a `_wp_http_referer` request field or fallback to the appropriate header for the referrer you can remove the `_wp_http_referer` query arg early on in the processing.

Therefore a simple way to resolve this issue is by adding the following very early on in the `prepare_items()` function of your `WP_List_Table` subclass.

```php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = remove_query_arg( '_wp_http_referer', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

B) The arguably better and more secure way would be to switch to the `POST` form submission method and update `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in `prepare_items()` with all the parameters you care about once you've compiled them so that `WP_List_Table::print_column_headers()` functions as expected.

```php
$options = array(
    'blog_id'     => $blog_id,
    's'           => $search,
    'record_type' => $record_type,
    'orderby'     => $orderby,
    'order'       => $order,
);

// Update the current URI with the new options.
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = add_query_arg( $options, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code just above the prepare_items() function

```php
if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['_wp_http_referer'] && ! empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) ) {
    $url = esc_url_raw( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
    $url = remove_query_arg( array( '_wp_http_referer', '_wpnonce' ), $url );

    wp_safe_redirect( $url );

    exit;
}
```